# Graphs from Table with multiple time series

Tags: microsoft-excel

I wish to create multiple graphs from the table below. Each graph should be based on the
value in Column2. I.e. 1 graph for CXC4012144 one for CXC4012234 etc and plot the values in Column 8 and 9 as two series. What I cannot work out is how to display only the data for a specific value in column 2 in each graph without filtering the table based on Column2 first ?

```
Column1 Column2 Column8 Column9
01/10/2023 02:00    CXC4012144  1   0
01/10/2023 02:00    CXC4012234  200000  3
01/10/2023 02:00    CXC4012282  38030000    419958
01/10/2023 02:00    CXC4012298  19015000    382638
01/10/2023 02:00    CXC4012300  19815000    411298
01/10/2023 02:00    CXC4012301  100000  40
01/10/2023 02:00    CXC4012362  5000    0
01/10/2023 02:00    CXC4012511  19015000    13
01/10/2023 02:00    CXC4012552  10000   39
01/10/2023 02:00    CXC4012553  10000   0
01/10/2023 02:00    CXC4012660  19015000    0
01/10/2023 03:00    CXC4012144  1   0
01/10/2023 03:00    CXC4012234  200000  3
01/10/2023 03:00    CXC4012282  38030000    577968
01/10/2023 03:00    CXC4012298  19015000    524803
01/10/2023 03:00    CXC4012300  19815000    565492
```

Comment: Couple of options: 1) sort on column B first then create each chart from the contiguous ranges, or 2) use a pivot chart

Comment: Did you try the Pivot Chart?